# finding members without e-mail addresses

Tags: civimember, email, search-builder

I'm trying to create a report of members who are expired who have not provided an e-mail address so I can mail them a form.

In search builder I am using `"membership status"=expired`, `contacts->email->is empty` and it is not working. Any ideas??

Comment: hey @tracey - thanks for asking your question. Quick tip: it's always good to include the version of CiviCRM that you're using in these types of questions

Answer (score 2):

Rather than `is empty` try using `is null` in your search.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be working fine on dmaster. Which version are you using? Make sure you have filled the details properly. See below for an example -

[image]